# Final variables in abstract classes

Tags: java, constructor, abstract, final

In Java, I can't create instances of abstract classes. So why doesn't eclipse scream about the following code?

```
public abstract class FooType {
    private final int myvar;

    public FooType() {
        myvar = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think that it should "scream" in the first place?

Comment: @aps red lines below the critical place (the assignment in the constructor, or constructor itself)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code is fine, the final variable is initialized in the constructor of `FooType`.

You cannot instantiate `FooType` because of it being abstract. But if you create a non abstract subclass of `FooType`, the constructor will be called.

If you do not have an explicit call to `super(...)` in a constructor, the Java Compiler will add it automatically. Therefore it is ensured that a constructor of every class in the inheritance chain is called.

Answer (score 3):

You can have constructors, methods, properties, everything in abstract classes that you can have in non-abstract classes as well. You just can't instantiate the class. So there is nothing wrong with this code.

In a deriving class you can call the constructor and set the final property:

```
public class Foo extends FooType
{
  public Foo()
  {
    super(); // <-- Call constructor of FooType
  }
}
```

if you don't specify a call to super(), it will be inserted anyway by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create concrete sub-classes of FooType and they will all have a final field called myvar.

BTW: A `public` constructor in an abstract class is the same as a `protected` one as it can only be called from a sub-class.

What is your doubt?

Comment: Ah, thats why eclipse eats it. See, i wanted to make an icon library in static context. But I wanted to load the from disk, so i cannot use final and static at once.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You can make a reference to an object which you load from disk static and final.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. See, an abstract class can have a constructor. It's always there-implicit or explicit. In fact when you create an object of a subclass of an abstract class, the first thing that the constructor of the subclass does is call the constructor of its abstract superclass by using super(). It is just understood, that's why you don't have to write `super()` explicitly unless you use parameterized constructors. Every class even if it is abstract, has an implicit constructor which you cannot see. It is called unless you create some constructor of your own. so long you created abstract classes without creating any custom constructor in it, so you didn't know about the existence of the implicit constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can declare final variable in abstract class as long as you assign value to it either in the constructor or in declaration. The example that guy gave makes no sense.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: I edited to remove the comment-like parts of what otherwise seems to be an answer. But please learn [answer] and take the [tour] to understand https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: The reason I decided to reply is that the first one popped up from googling "can we declare final variable in abstract" is the wrong answer, which is so sad to see the answer from stackoverflow. Hope you can get what I mean.

Comment: If you decided to reply then please reply, ideally according to [answer]. But then writing "Do not have 50 reputation to comment." does not make any sense. That only goes with you intending to comment, because only commenting is restricted to having 50 reputation - while replying/answering only requires to actually answer the question at the top of the page.

Comment: The easiest way to let people know the answer is wrong is to comment instead of adding a new answer given the situation that the wrong answer is selected as "correct answer" by google. I totally know what you mean. The question has been 10 years, and I am surprised that no one pointed out that. If "Do not have 50 reputation to comment." is bad, just remove it. I have no problems with it. I think you somehow misunderstood what I mean. I replied not because of 50 reputation but the wrong answer popped from Googling the question.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "the wrong answer is selected as "correct answer" by google". I am not aware of any search engine with that feature related to answers here. StackOverflows "green tick" feature does NOT mean "correct answer". It only means "this answer was most helpful for the question author". And still, if you know the rule, please do not decide to misuse an answer post for what it is not meant for. You can find more info on this concept (and others) on the highly recommended [tour]. It might help you to avoid doing unappreciated things - instead of letting other remove them.

Comment: For "No idea what you mean by "the wrong answer is selected as "correct answer" by google", could you search "can we declare final variable in abstract" in google? You will know what I mean by the wrong answer is selected as "correct answer". I didn't know mentioning 50 reputation to comment is a bad thing. This reply is to solve your confusion that you mentioned in last reply.

Comment: I did google as proposed. And yes, google does seem to try giving "the correct" answer. But it does not actually say so (or I missed it). What you get is "an answer" and I have the impression that google is going more by linguistics than other aspects, surely not "correctness" - how could they. There is no guaranteed way to find a correct answer. But the least questionable way is what StackOverflow offers to identify the most plausible one. The voting. Sadly, google seems not to care...

Comment: Thank you for searching the question. I was reviewing some Java questions. Then, I googled the question, and saw the answer. I didn't believe the answer was correct but no one mentioned it was wrong. Finally I tried the code in my IDE. Thanks for your understanding. Hopefully, no candidates gave that wrong answer during the interview.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't declare final variables inside an Abstract class.
Check Below example.

```
public abstract class AbstractEx {
    final int x=10;
    public abstract void AbstractEx();
}

public class newClass extends AbstractEx{

    public void AbstractEx(){
        System.out.println("abc");
        }
    }  

public class declareClass{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       AbstractEx obj = new newClass ();
       obj.AbstractEx();
      // System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

This code runs correct and produce output as

> abc

But if we remove comment symbol of

> System.out.println(x);

it will produce error.